# Spring Hibernate/JPA Postgres: value too long for type character varying(255)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to setup relationships from Spring Boot, Hibernate/JPA but after trying the whole day and today morning, it hasn't worked.  I have received several errors but now the error is limited to:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: value too long for type character varying(255)
```

Below are my POJOs:

```
@Entity
public class ParentEvent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long _id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parentEvent")
    private List<ChildEvent> childEvent;

    // other getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class ChildEvent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentEvent__id")
    private ParentEvent parentEvent;

    // other getters and setters ..
}
```

And I have the following json structure:

```
parentEvent: {
    childEvent: [
        {
            param1: "value",
            param2: "value",
        },
        {
            param1: "value",
            param2: "value",
        },
    ]
}
```

I have gone through several stackoverflow posts and tutorials and the above structure looks fine, but I am unable to get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is param1/2 in entity class? Please show code

Comment: *What am I doing wrong?* you're trying to store a string that has more than 255 characters into a database column which can only contain 255 characters. None of what you posted allows us to be more precise than that.

Comment: @JBNizet that is correct, I set the text/description column as "@Column(length=10485760)" and that resolved the issue.

Comment: It is working, however, in the "child_event" table, the "_id" of "parent_event" is not populating.  How can I make the ParentEvent._id populate in ChildEvent.parentEvent__id column?

Comment: This question has been asked a thousand times. The parentEvent__id column is mapped to the ChildEvent.parentEvent property. So if ChildEvent.parentEvent is null, the column value will be null too. Corollary: if you want a non-null value into the column, you need to set ChildEvent.parentEvent to a non-null value.

Answer (score 5):

If you use PostgreSQL you can use the following annotation:

```
@Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
```

But this will not work with other databases.